# Groupby in mapreduce program

Tags: python, hadoop, mapreduce

I have got a huge file 200K records to process.

I need to find the the average product price based on the region , product type for a given year using python

Comment: 200k isn't necessarily huge (depending on how wide the dataset is). Have you tried simply loading it into a Pandas Dataframe and processing it that way? Regardless, I'd have a hard time recommending that anyone solve a problem with MapReduce in 2021.

Comment: If you want to use MapReduce, start with `mrjob` library. Otherwise `groupBy` or `agg`/`avg` are literally PySpark Dataframe methods, although starting with Pandas is always a good choice